# How can i add arrow bullets in ck-editor?

Tags: ckeditor

How can i add arrow bullets in ck-editor?
currently i can see only square,disc,and circle.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbuxV.png)

Comment: Use custom bullet for that. Like `li:before`

Comment: sir can you please explain it with example, that would be very helpful,sorry i did not not understand what you answered.

Comment: @KalpeshKoli https://techforluddites.com/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `li` bullets using `:before` pseudo elements

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/arrow/images/6/64/Favicon.ico/revision/latest?cb=20121123054146') no-repeat center center;
  display: block;
  left: -20px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Trext</li>
  <li>Tesfd</li>
  <li>Tesddf</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you  very much for your reply...actually i want to add arrow bullet list inside ckeditor where we get bullet option in ckeditor, i should be able to select arrow bullets , currently i can see 3 option when i right click on the bullet and go to bullet list properties i get square,disc,circle here i should be able to see arrow bullet option...i have also updated question with screen short...the answer which gave with that if it is possible then where should i implement that code inside css file or js? i am not sure where to put it..hope you will help sir thankyou